# which one is better for drag drop resizing moving

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I am new to html5.I have two panels or you can say div.and I want to drag and drop images from one panel to other and then resize it or move it around the panel.
I have been reading about different options

- jquery
- kinetic js
- html5 canvas
- javascript

and I am totally confused which one to use? and which one best fits my case.Any help would be appreciated 
also isnt canvas is when you draw something rather then using readymade images?

Answer (score 0):

jquery can do this very well, i don't know about kinetic js.
html5 canvas would be too much complicated for doing such a thing. (In my opinion)

And javascript is the language you need to use in your html document to play with drag & drops so working with jquery is working with javascript.

Take a look at jQuery drag&drop http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/